# If I plan to retire in Puerto Rico, should I move my 401k anywhere?

Tags: united-states, ira, rollover, puerto-rico

I plan to retire to Puerto Rico. Should I rollover my 401k directly to an IRA in Puerto Rico or should I keep it in the US?

Comment: Puerto Rico is part of the US so there is nothing special here.  I'd keep it in a mainland based bank given all financial issues in Puerto Rico these days.

Comment: @Kekito I live in PR, and your warning is both invalid and needlessly alarmist. PR banks operate under the same federal regulations as in the US. Rolling over the account to a PR bank is no riskier than rolling it over to any other US bank.

Comment: Hey @OP, was there some rationale we're all missing for why you thought rolling it over to a Puerto Rico-based IRA would help you?  Is this just a question rolling over a 401k to an IRA?

Comment: Puerto Rico is a US commonwealth but they do not pay federal taxes and do not participate in the same IRA and 401K system as the rest of the US, so it's a valid and complex question, which the OP may need to ask a paid expert about. Puerto Rico has an "IRA" system but it's completely separate from the US system and it's not clear that you *can* transfer from one system to the other.

Comment: see https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/72059/federal-taxes-on-retirement-money-puerto-rico-taxes-after-retirement